# How to select specific node using Html Agility Pack?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

`<div class="form-field wide-80 normal">1997-09-15</div>`

I am trying to select the date inside it 1997-09-15. I tried this code but its giving an error of "Xpath Exception was Unhandled" what's wrong in the code please Help

```
 string Url = "http://whois.domaintools.com/google.com";

 HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

 var SpanNodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=form-field wide-80 normal]");
 if (SpanNodes != null)
 {
      foreach (HtmlNode SN in SpanNodes)
      {
          string text = SN.FirstChild.InnerText.Trim();
          MessageBox.Show(text);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget `'`s

```
var SpanNodes = 
       doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='form-field wide-80 normal']");
```

Comment: That and .FirstChild.InnerText is not needed, you can actually grab the text directly: `//div[@class='form-field wide-80 normal']/text()`

Comment: Did what you corrected but its not working...its not giving any result please help

Comment: <font face=arial><b>Results for google.com :</b></font><p><font  face=arial><b>Domain Created on:</b><br>September 15 1997<br><br><b>Domain age (approximately):</b><br>15 Years, 7 Months, 24 days.</font>                                                        How can i select date from here ?????

Comment: @user2233501 But it works. It shows 29 entries in collection.

Comment: but not showing for me please is there any thing wrong which i am doing and did you used the same code as above?

Comment: @user2233501 Just replace your for-loop with `var textList = SpanNodes.Select(x => x.InnerText).ToList();`

Comment: i did this but still not working Please see the code below i am trying again and again to get it work

Comment: Have you read the message `Thank you for using the DomainTools for your domain research. To protect domain registrants we limit the number of anonymous whois lookups that are allowed. We wish that you will continue using our service for domain information but ask that you create and **log into a DomainTools account** before doing any more lookups.`

Comment: Yeah i'll take care about that next time :) But please help me to get this work

Comment: @user2233501 What do you want me to do. I say It works..(at least worked). You get the above error and no data. `i'll take care about that next time` -> No you have to deal with it right now. Open your browser and navigate to that page......

Comment: Yeah i have created a account on whois.sc